# What do the different colours of items mean?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Is there some logic to the way items are coloured in Baldur's Gate 3?

Sometimes e.g. green items (which seem most common) are more powerful than, say, blue items.
And some items only have a coloured border, whereas others have coloured backgrounds or gradients.

What do these traits all mean?

Answer (score 4):

- **Orange borders without background**

  Orange bordered items with black/transparent backgrounds are **items needed for quests** (they don't always have to be in your inventory, sometimes just having picked them up is sufficient). These items can't be added to your wares.
  This classification overrides others (the Staff of Crones has no coloured background nor halo, yet is uncommon and magical).

  [image: icon of the Spectral-Touched Tadpole]
- **Coloured borders and backgrounds**

  Generally, the colour simply indicates **item rarity**. These rarity colours are visible in the border and a gradient from the bottom upwards:

  [image: icon of The Common Shovel] [image: icon of an uncommon bow] [image: icon of a rare pendant] [image: icon of a very rare helmet] [image: icon of a legendary spear]

  All item borders are either uncoloured, green, blue, purple, or orange. These correspond to '*common*', '*uncommon*', '*rare*', '*very rare*', and '*legendary*' items:

  | Border and background colour |  | Item rarity |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | None |  | Common |
  | Green | [image: green] | Uncommon |
  | Blue | [image: blue] | Rare |
  | Purple | [image: purple] | Very Rare |
  | Orange (note how it's slightly more yellow than that of the quest item border) | [image: orange] | Legendary |

  - An item having no coloured border and background means it is non-magical and common.
    Examples are the lowest tiers of armour and weapons, saleworthy items such as rings and necklaces, but also rags, rotten food items, and other trash.
- **Item auras/halos**

  An aura usually seems to signify that an item has magical properties. And even that's not always true.
  In short: **an aura and its colour do not imply anything**.

  Most items have yellow auras, but not all of them: there are also auras in red and different shades of blue. The reasons behind these colours are <del>harder</del> impossible to figure out. Here are a few observations, though:

  - Yellow auras and rays seem to indicate magical items (not necessarily with any properties beneficial to the player).
  - Light-blue halos (white aura with blue rays) seem to broadly point out conditional ("*Whenever*/*When*/*If*/*While*/*As long as*" in the description) and chance-based (effects, Reaction) properties.
  - The *Grymskull Helm* has a subtle but distinct greenish-blue aura. It's the only item with this colour I've encountered so far.
  - Another arguable interpretation is that these colours are class-based, and items with a light-blue aura are useable by and useful for any class. This is based on the fact that the few items with a red aura I found (namely, the *Linebreaker Boots* that give Wrath, and *Reason's Grasp*, which gives temporary hit points when ending one's Rage) were mostly useful for close combat classes, and the one item I have with a light purple glow (the *Potent Robe*), is most useful for a sorcerer.
  - An even subtler differentiation is that between the use of rays and stars (in the background, not on top of the item, most pronounced in the icon of the *Boots of Psionic Movement*, depicted below), but I cannot find any denominator that would make for a useful division:

    [image: icon for the Boots of Psionic Movement]
  - To complicate matters further, items like the *Ring of Exalted Marrow*, *Selûne's Spear of Night*, and the *Shield of Devotion*, have no aura whatsoever. The *Crooked Wand of Fireballs* doesn't even have any other colour, nor a mention of rarity.
  - If we start throwing potions in the mix, however, this already hopeless analysis becomes completely bonkers: red dye, for example, has a red aura, and there is no reason to assume it's magical.

Comment: basically the aura just means it looks cooler :)

Comment: Items made of adamantine via the forge also have a blue-green aura in the tooltip art (I confirm mace and scale mail from my recent playthrough). Since Grym is an adamantine golem iirc, that color used to distinguish adamantine items would track

Comment: It also seems Purple items generally have +2 enhancements. Leaving this as a comment for now.